# Move Files Older Than 3 BUSINESS days from One Directory To Another

Tags: powershell

I know I've seen people answer the more simple, "move files older than N days from one folder to another question" but i want to introduce two necessary additions to this.  I need to be able to move files that are older than three BUSINESS days (Mon-Fri) AND, i need to set both directories (the from and the to directories) to variables as this is likely to change frequently.

I assume Powershell is the way to go here but am still learning.  Let me know if additional information is needed or if someone is able to assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about holidays? Or would the simple condition "if it's monday  then older than N+2 days else older than N days" (plus according checks if running on saturday or sunday) meet your needs?

Comment: have you tried starting with one of those other answers, and modifying it for your needs?  We're here to help you answer *specific* questions, not general ones.

Comment: Hi John - apologies, i do feel this is very specific.  Let me know how to make it more specific.  I have tried to modify an existing script but am unable to get it to work.  Holidays do not need to be factored in.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

First you'll need to define the number of days to exclude and the current numerical day of the week.

```
$days = 3
$DOW = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__
```

You also wanted the file paths configured.

```
$from = "C:\old"
$to = "c:\new"
```

This will set the threshold to the morning minus however many days you've defined. If that overlaps a weekend it will back up the threshold two more days.

```
$threshold = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays((0-$days))
if ($DOW -lt $days) {
    $threshold = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays((0-$days-2))
    }
```

Once the hard part is done you can just get the files that are older than the threshold and move them.

```
Get-ChildItem $from | Where-Object $lastWriteTime -lt $threshold | Move-Item $to
```

There are several areas where this could use some tweaking depending on your needs. First, I understand that `(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__` may be dependent on your locale, so you may need to tweak some of the math that uses that date. Also, if you're wanting to maintain the file and folder structure throughout the move action, the last line may need to become more complex.

Comment: Tim - this is extremely helpful and I've been able to sort through and make sense of it due to your great explanation.  As you noted, I am running into a date issue with the less than comparison as it is trying to compare a date to a number.  In this case

if ($DOW -lt $threshold)

DOW string returns a '3' for Wednesday.  Threshhold is returning '6/1/2014 12:00:00 AM' (day minus 3) which aren't able to compare.  Is there a way to convert the threshhold value to a numeric for comparison purposes?

Comment: Sorry, that should've been $DOW -Lt $days. Fixed.

Comment: The compare, if ($DOW -lt $threshold), is comparing a numeric value 1 (today) and a date string (minus 2 days), Saturday, June 21, 2014 12:00:00 AM.  Any idea on a good route to convert these so that the compare is able to work?  I'm getting the error - Bad argument to operator '-lt': Could not compare "1" to "6/21/2014 12:00:00 AM". Error: "Cannot convert value "6/21/2014 12:00:00 AM" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'."".  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer several weeks ago, also commented on the fix.